# Which part of Windows are irreplacable?

Tags: windows, backup, windows-backup

Let's say you are tasked with backing up a Windows installation. You could back up **everything**, but that's inefficient. One can make a backup more compact by considering these directories:

> **(1)** Much of what can be found in `C:/WINDOWS` is also replaceable by just reinstalling the system from scratch (and although you may not get back the *exact* binaries you had on the system due to updates, there is seldom a logical reason to hold onto old versions of Windows system files).
>
> **(2)** *Most* of the things in `C:/Program Files` is replaceable; for instance if you want to get FireFox up and running again, just re-download the binaries from their website. Even large pieces of software such as Adobe's over-priced Creative Suite is reconstructible provided you back up the easy to store key.
>
> **(3)** The data that **is** irreplaceable is pretty much everything in `C:/Users` (especially in the oft-forgotten subdirectories related to `AppData`). This obviously needs to be backed up.

Aside from those three obvious locations, what other parts of a Windows can or cannot be replaced, and should be considered when backing up a Windows system?

For instance, from what I understand, the registry (which will have unique data in) is actually stored physically somewhere on the harddrive as well.

Comment: I'm not sure if those three points should be cluttering up the question (I would rather have them in an answer), but I included them to illustrate what sort of answers I am looking for. If you write an answer to this question, feel free to include those three points in your answer to fill it out, then I can remove that paragraph from this question.

Comment: on a server, where you run one app, and its data can be stored externally, you are correct, it makes sense to just back up the apps data. Desktops are a differant kind of animal however and have a much more complex relationship between their OS kernel, components, and applications, most especially because of the system Registry. I'd caution you to consider other strategies like moving your profile to another drive with your other user data, and backing it up, instead of trying to do the any of the system, and accept that you will have to reinstall and reconfigure apps if the box goes belly up.

Answer (score 2):

**Theory**

The irreplaceable stuff is *user data*, as you identified yourself. User data is found in `C:\Users`, which includes `ntuser.dat` for each user (that's the user registry file which becomes `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` when the user logs on).

Everything that is not user data is replaceable in theory.

One big gotcha is software that is not Windows Logo Compliant. Such software might store user data anywhere on the system (though Windows Vista and later tries to redirect such behaviours to user profile locations, under `C:\Users`, where possible).

**Practicality**

In the event of total data loss, re-installing Windows + applications + all user data is a nightmare in its own right. Invariably you discover some software didn't store user data where it should have or requires *re-activation* etc.

If I was going to invest in a comprehensive backup strategy, I'd go for the ***sector-based incremental*** method. This kind of backup actually reads the individual sectors of a hard drive, but only backs up those sectors that have changed since the previous backup. Obviously the first backup includes everything so it's big, but subsequent backups are incremental and much smaller.

Some softwarem like Photoshop CS2, has copy protection (Macrovision) that writes data to sectors between the MBR and first partition. The OS file system is completely unaware of this and file-based backups fail to backup the copy protection. However, sector-based backup does notice the changed sectors and backs them up perfectly.

**EDIT:**  As always, there's no such thing as a sliver bullet. Sector-based incremental backups only work efficiently if you *don't* defrag your hard drive, because a defrag physically re-arranges files thereby modifying a lot of sectors.

This becomes a non-issue with SSD hard drives because, generally, you don't need to defrag (though some folks still do). But then restoring a sector backup to SSD necessitates running a manual TRIM afterwards to restore SSD performance. And it wears out the SSD more so than a file-based restore.

Thanks to **kinokijuf** for bringing up the defrag issue!

Comment: Sectror-based backup is baaad when you take disk defrag into consideration. Better use tools that are NTFS-aware.

Comment: @kinokijuf Are you sure sector-based backups are *bad*? Bad how? In my experience they achieve a 1:1 perfect backup in a way that file-based methods can't (or haven't for me anyway). Sure, an initial backup is big but with compression it's not that bad. Then the incrementals are pretty small. Mind you, I only do sector-based backups on my primary drive which is 128GB. I wouldn't do it on my media drive which is 2TB. Anyway I guess it comes down to what your needs are. If you want true 1:1, sector-based achieves that.

Comment: @kinokijuf I just remembered what drove me to use sector-based backups in the first place. Photoshop CS2. Brilliant software, but evil copy protection (Macrovision) which writes data to sectors between the MBR and first partition. The OS file system is completely unaware of this and file-based backups fail to backup the stupid copy protection. However, sector-based backup does notice the changed sectors and backs them up perfectly.

Comment: I think the point @kinokijuf was making is that if you regularly defragment the drive (not necessary or a good idea), everything that process does does shows up as sector changes, so you would repeatedly have big, slow, "initial" backups.  Can you address that in your answer?

Comment: @fixer1234 Of course! How did I not get that, my apologies.

Comment: Microsoft and others now recommend to not routinely defrag the drives.  It has little effect on performance unless there is really significant fragmentation and there is a risk of corruption from the defrag process.

Comment: What about `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` and other "non-user" registry data? (I'd consider that irreplaceable information) Where is that stored?

Comment: @IQAndreas `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` is not user data so in theory it is replaceable. How? By reinstalling windows, drivers, updates, apps, and then configuring everything to the way you like it. That's the *nightmare* I'm talking about when restoring. Anyway, if you want to back up `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`, you can only back up portions of it according to app vendor instructions. Here's an example: http://www.sophos.com/en-us/support/knowledgebase/27265.aspx. Surely you can appreciate now why I *love* sector-based backups ;-)